# Is it possible to share the same list type among different sites?

Tags: web-part, list, web-services

I'm accessing list content via its corresponding webservice. I'm re-creating new lists for new sites but often the list content type is the same - image, link etc.... Is it possible to create a list type which can be re-used and added to multiple sites to access the content using the same service. To access the content from different sites I could use a parameter as part of the REST endpoint which determines which site I'm referring to ?

So for example :

I have a predefined list called 'imageListField' which just stores an image. When I create a site : 'site1' I add the field 'imageListField' to this site (site1). I then create a new site 'site2' and add the same field 'imageListField' to this site (site2). Is it possible for 'imageListField' to contain different images for the two different sites (site1 & site2) Can I access the contents of imageListField for 'site1' & 'site2' via its web service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you want to do but each list will have its own unique endpoint  e.g:
    http: // contoso/sites/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ListName()

That is how you determine which site you refer to.

You can have a reusable list definition and content type if you deploy them as a feature, then you can activate them in any web.

Comment: thanks, I've updated my question, hope this better explains what I'm trying to do.